# Android activity not responding to touches event Dropping event due to no window focus

Tags: android, material-design, activity-transition

Activity A starts activity B for results:

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(ActivityA.this, ActivityB.class);
                    ActivityOptionsCompat transitionActivityOptions = ActivityOptionsCompat.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(NewInvoiceActivity.this);
                    Bundle b = transitionActivityOptions.toBundle();
                    intent.putExtra("project_name", (String) projectName);
                    intent.putExtra("project_id", projectID);
                    startActivityForResult(intent, InvoiceItemSelectActivity.REQUEST_SELECT_ITEMS, b);
```

then in the onCreateView in Activity B :

```
        Explode e = new Explode();
        e.setDuration(400);
        getWindow().setEnterTransition(e);
        getWindow().setExitTransition(e);
        getWindow().setStatusBarColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.primary));
```

and on inside Activity B a button setOnClickListener .... :

```
            Intent resultIntent = new Intent();

            resultIntent.putExtra("items", "some data");
            setResult(RESULT_OK, resultIntent);
            finish();
```

after returning to A, activity A becomes untouchable in the log:

```
08-25 11:46:21.658  1481  1481 W ViewRootImpl: Dropping event due to no window focus: 
08-25 11:46:21.658  1481  1481 E ViewRootImpl: mStopped=false mHasWindowFocus=true mPausedForTransition=true
```

I'm testing on Android 6.0.1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

in Activity B replacing

```
            finish();
```

by

```
            finishAfterTransition();
```

seems to solve the issue.
somehow Activity A keeps `mPausedForTransition=true`paused waiting for a Transition animation that never happens,unless you call `finishAfterTransition`

Answer (score -2):

U need try with something like

```
activity.requestFocus();
```

Comment: but is this necessary it doesn't feel natural in onActivityResults ?